# If strings are immutable in .NET, then why does Substring take O(n) time?

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, time-complexity

Given that strings are immutable in .NET, I'm wondering why they have been designed such that `string.Substring()` takes O(`substring.Length`) time, instead of `O(1)`?

i.e. what were the tradeoffs, if any?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I like this question. Could you please tell me how we can determine O() of a given function in .Net? Is it clear or we should calculate it?  Thank you

Comment: @odiseh: Sometimes (like in this case) it's clear that the string is being copied. If it isn't, then you could either look in the documentation, perform benchmarks, or try to look in the .NET Framework source code to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

UPDATE: I liked this question so much, I just blogged it. See [Strings, immutability and persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/strings-immutability-and-persistence)

---

The short answer is: **O(n) is O(1) if n does not grow large.**  Most people extract tiny substrings from tiny strings, so how the complexity grows asymptotically is *completely irrelevant*.

The long answer is:

An immutable data structure built such that operations on an instance permit re-use of the memory of the original with only a small amount (typically O(1) or O(lg n)) of copying or new allocation is called a "persistent" immutable data structure. Strings in .NET are immutable; your question is essentially "why are they not persistent"?

Because when you look at operations that are *typically* done on strings in .NET programs, it is in every relevant way *hardly worse at all* to simply make an entirely new string. **The expense and difficulty of building a complex persistent data structure doesn't pay for itself.**

People typically use "substring" to extract a short string -- say, ten or twenty characters -- out of a somewhat longer string -- maybe a couple hundred characters. You have a line of text in a comma-separated file and you want to extract the third field, which is a last name. The line will be maybe a couple hundred characters long, the name will be a couple dozen. String allocation and memory copying of fifty bytes is *astonishingly fast* on modern hardware. That making a new data structure that consists of a pointer to the middle of an existing string plus a length is *also* astonishingly fast is irrelevant; "fast enough" is by definition fast enough.

The substrings extracted are typically small in size and short in lifetime; the garbage collector is going to reclaim them soon, and they didn't take up much room on the heap in the first place. So using a persistent strategy that encourages reuse of most of the memory is also not a win; all you've done is made your garbage collector get slower because now it has to worry about handling interior pointers.

If the substring operations people typically did on strings were completely different, then it would make sense to go with a persistent approach. If people typically had million-character strings, and were extracting thousands of overlapping substrings with sizes in the hundred-thousand-character range, and those substrings lived a long time on the heap, then it would make perfect sense to go with a persistent substring approach; it would be wasteful and foolish not to. But **most line-of-business programmers do not do anything even vaguely like those sorts of things**. .NET is not a platform that is tailored for the needs of the Human Genome Project; DNA analysis programmers have to solve problems with those string usage characteristics every day; odds are good that you do not. The few who do build their own persistent data structures that closely match *their* usage scenarios.

For example, my team writes programs that do on-the-fly analysis of C# and VB code as you type it. Some of those code files are *enormous* and thus we cannot be doing O(n) string manipulation to extract substrings or insert or delete characters. We have built a bunch of persistent immutable data structures for representing edits to a text buffer that permit us to quickly and efficiently re-use the bulk of the existing string data *and* the existing lexical and syntactic analyses upon a typical edit. This was a hard problem to solve and its solution was narrowly tailored to the specific domain of C# and VB code editing. It would be unrealistic to expect the built-in string type to solve this problem for us.

Comment: It would be interesting to contrast how Java does (or at least did at some point in the past) it: Substring returns a new string, but pointing at the same char[] as the larger string - that means that the larger char[] can no longer be garbage collected until the substring goes out of scope. I prefer .net's implementation by far.

Comment: I've seen this sort of code quite a bit: `string contents = File.ReadAllText(filename); foreach (string line in content.Split("\n")) ...` or other versions of it. I mean read an entire file, then process the various parts. That sort of code would be considerably faster and require less memory if a string was persistent; you would always have exactly one copy of the file in memory instead of copying each line, then the parts of each line as your process it. However, like Eric said - that is not the typical use case.

Comment: @configurator: Also, in .NET 4 the File.ReadLines method breaks up a text file into lines for you, without having to read it all into memory first.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Yes, of course. The point was that sometimes a large string is read and the processed part by part - it doesn't matter if it's split by newline or by empty lines (e.g. `.Split("\r\n\r\n")`), or whatever the protocol requires.

Comment: @Michael: Java's `String` is implemented as a persistent data structure (that's not specified in the standards, but all implementations I know of do this).

Comment: Short answer: A copy of the data is made *to allow garbage collection of the original string*.

Comment: I guess you could optimise this for pinned GCHandles, but you would probably end up losing microseconds of perf cause of the extra switching :)

Comment: It is notable that in the File.ReadAllText example, disk operations are several orders of magnitude slower than in-memory copying so the O(n)-ness is still irrelevant.

Comment: The alternative of copying would be very dangerous and prone to unsuspecting memory leaks. If we read a big string from disk and keep a substring from it for later processing it would be against a lot of people expectations (mine included) that the initial memory would not be collected. This will cause so many subtle and impossible to track issues in most of the code out there that whole systems would crumble and development will become 10 times harder - we'll be back in C++ again.

Comment: "Most people extract tiny substrings from tiny strings, so how the complexity grows asymptotically is completely irrelevant". That is a circular argument. Most people extract tiny substrings because extracting large substrings is so slow. There are obvious applications for bisection and tail...

Comment: "By persistent, I mean...can re-use most or all of the memory of an existing data structure". In the context of data structures, the word "persistent" is usually used to mean "updates create new data structures without destroying old ones". For example, see http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/Persistence.htm

Comment: For the specific case of `Substring()`, new programming languages such as D and Go offer the "slice" data type (implemented as a pointer + length, or a pair of pointers) which makes `Substring()` extremely fast. The D language does not even *have* a "real" array or string data type; when you create a string, the language gives you a slice through which to access it. D strings are immutable, so changing a string or concatenating still takes `O(Length)`. It would be great if .NET could support slices.

Comment: @JonHarrop String does give you a lot of methods that work with explicitly passed index-and-length. This enables you to implement something quite like slicing where it's needed. Or, if you really need to, you can use unsafe code. As Eric said, if you're writing your own database or a DNA analyzer, you probably know what you're doing, and you have your own way of working with strings.

Comment: @Luaan: The first thing anyone wants to do with a string is parse bits of it into ints, floats, datetimes etc. How many of those `Parse` functions accept an offset and length?

Comment: @JonHarrop Yeah, that's a great example. When I actually had to write a high performance parser of DBFs (which is exactly the scenario your talking about), I had to make my own parsing routines. An alternative might be to use streams (`StringReader` and co.), which allow you to save a lot of allocations by reusing the same char arrays over and over again. However, I'd like to point out that BCLs number parsing routines are actually quite slow (but safe!). In my case, better memory allocation patterns saved maybe 3-5% CPU time. Faster parsing - 70%. .NET's memory management is quite good :)

Comment: @cdiggins " Wrong wrong wrong wrong wrong. C'mon!!" -- C'mon yourself. If n is bounded by a constant C, then O(n) = O(C) = O(1).

Comment: "The D language does not even have a "real" array or string data type; when you create a string, the language gives you a slice through which to access it. D strings are immutable, so changing a string or concatenating still takes O(Length)." -- This is completely wrong.

Comment: @JimBalter "This is completely wrong" can you explain why or offer an alternative analysis that is correct? Without that your comment is not very helpful.

Comment: @phoog The D language is not the subject here; feel free to go read up on it. The D language certainly has real arrays. strings are immutable char arrays, that come in three flavors, string, wstring, and dstring, for the three sizes of unicode encoding. Slices are a different beast ... they are "cursors" that reference a section of an array. When you create an array, you do not get a slice ... a slice is something that you create independently.

Comment: FYI, this design mistake has now been fixed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Isak: I wouldn't call it a design mistake. It's a conscious decision that compared with the other option is fairly surprise-free. Java noticed the hard way that having persistent strings as the default has all kinds of trouble with certain usage patterns as you sometimes would have a very long-lived and hard to trace down giant string object lying around. So they ended up changing that behaviour as well. From an API design POV I'd say both options should be available, as they are now. But Span makes it clear to the reader as well that you have a view onto another object instead of a copy.

Comment: Yea strings get internet via the string pool just like a database abstraction uses a connection pool. That’s where bounded contexts in the form of thread safe queues come from. We can never assume we have infinite memory. We don’t. We can however scale vertically and or horizontally. It depends. Also should we ever run a node or rails app without a reverse proxy ? Heck no!

Answer (score 123):

Precisely *because* Strings are immutable, `.Substring` must make a copy of at least a portion of the original string.   Making a copy of *n* bytes should take O(n) time.

How do you think you would copy a bunch of bytes in *constant* time?

---

EDIT: Mehrdad suggests not copying the string at all, but keeping a reference to a piece of it.

Consider in .Net, a multi-megabyte string, on which someone calls `.SubString(n, n+3)` (for any n in the middle of the string).

Now, the ENTIRE string cannot be Garbage Collected just because one reference is holding on to 4 characters?
That seems like a ridiculous waste of space.

Further, tracking references to substrings (which may even be inside substrings), and trying to copy at optimal times to avoid defeating the GC (as described above), makes the concept a nightmare.  It is far simpler, and more reliable, to copy on `.SubString`, and maintain the straightforward immutable model.

---

**EDIT:**  Here's a [**good little read**](http://www.thegrumpyprogrammer.com/2015/08/my-favorite-bugs-java-memory-leak.html) about the danger of keeping references to substrings within larger strings.

Comment: +1: Exactly my thoughts. Internally it probably uses `memcpy` which is still O(n).

Comment: @abelenky: I guess maybe by not copying it at all? It's already there, why should you have to copy it?

Comment: @Mehrdad, unless the substring you're returning happens to be the right-most part of the string, it has to copy the substring in order to put a new null terminator byte.

Comment: @Samuel: Null-terminator? Is it required in .NET?

Comment: @abelenky: Nice edit, that's definitely something I didn't think of (although it's something that isn't too much of a problem -- e.g. it can be easily fixed by letting the user use `string.Copy`). +1

Comment: @Mehrdad: IF you are after performance. Just go unsafe in this case. Then you can get a `char*` substring.

Comment: @leppie: Yeah, although then I'd have to manually implement and/or call `strlen`, `strstr`, etc... though of course it's doable.

Comment: @Mehrdad, yes, strings in .NET are null-terminated. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

Comment: @Mehrdad: Always a hard choice :) Have you tried 'truncating' a `StringBuilder` to see if it is any faster (assuming you dont need the old string)?

Comment: @leppie: `StringBuilder` is a pain in the rear to work with, unless all you're doing is concatenation or simple manipulation. As soon as you try doing an `IndexOf` to find a substring and then copy it, it's impractical to use (and besides, you often need the original string because you're searching in it again).

Comment: @Mehrdad - you might be expecting too much there, it's called **StringBuilder**, and it's good a **building** strings. It's not called StringMultiPurposeManipulator

Comment: @MattDarvey: lol, I was just explaining why it's often not a good substitute for `char*` or `string`. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad - Fair enough :) StringBuilder is what I like to call a Ronseal class - it does exactly what it says on the tin! That probably doesn't make any sense unless you're British :)

Comment: @SamuelNeff, @Mehrdad: Strings in .NET are **not** `NULL` terminated. As explained in [Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx), the first 4 bytes contain the length of the string. That's why, as Skeet points out, they can contain `\0` characters.

Comment: I go on: The internal array contains a `\0` at the end ([Memory usage section](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)), but just for unmanaged code's sake. Only when passing optimized substrings to unmanaged code would a copy of it be needed to add the `NULL`.

Comment: @Elideb, I said that strings have a null character at the end.  Which is consistent with Jon Skeet said Eric Lippert said.  Yes, the null is there for unmanaged interoperability and not a true indicator of the end of the string, but the fact is the strings do all have a null character at the end.

Comment: @Samuel Neff: If strings in .NET were changed to be persistent then they could also be changed not to be null terminated. Sure, that would make unmanaged interop require a copy of the string first, but that's a choice you could reasonably make. Substring operations probably occur more often than interop.

Comment: @Joren, depends entirely on the app.  I'm sure in our application we do thousands of interop calls for every substring call.

Comment: @Mehrdad your link says String can contain null. That doesn't mean they are null terminated.

Comment: Java does substrings by keeping a reference to the original string (or rather, its underlying char array). It is not a nightmare at all; turns out that keeping around only a tiny substring of a huge string is just as about as rare as creating lots of large substrings. It very rarely causes problems.

Comment: @abelenky "the ENTIRE string cannot be Garbage Collected just because one reference is holding on to 4 characters". The GC could be made responsible for the copying, replacing substrings with explicit strings as it goes. Moreover, the GC can do this more efficiently by taking memory pressure and sparsity of reference into account.

Comment: @abelenky: "tracking references to substrings (which may even be inside substrings), and trying to copy at optimal times to avoid defeating the GC (as described above), makes the concept a nightmare". Note that substrings of substrings can be trivially simplified to substrings of arrays.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt "keeping around only a tiny substring of a huge string is just as about as rare as creating lots of large substrings". Beware of self-selection. IMO, those things are only rare on .NET because .NET does not handle them well so most people have learned to avoid them. I have 550kLOC of VB code here for a LOB app (document generation) that uses repeated naive string concatenation and is too slow as a consequence.

Comment: @JD StringBuilder ftw?

Answer (score 33):

Java (as opposed to .NET) provides two ways of doing `Substring()`, you can consider whether you want to keep just a reference or copy a whole substring to a new memory location.

The simple `.substring(...)` shares the internally used `char` array with the original String object, which you then with `new String(...)` can copy to a new array, if needed (to avoid hindering garbage collection of the original one).

I think this kind of flexibility is a best option for a developer.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Originally' here? Was this removed?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: sorry for confusion, I believe this is because of my pure English, apologize

Comment: You call it "flexibility" I call it "A way to accidentally insert a hard to diagnose bug (or a performance problem) into the software because I didn't realize I have to stop and think about all the places this code can possibly be called from (including those that would only be invented in the next version) just to get 4 characters from the middle of a string"

Comment: From the scratch, development it is not an easy thing and requires a lot of knowledge, but really you are right, newbies can use such stuff in wrong and this often cause problems

Comment: downvote retracted...  After a bit more careful browsing of code it does look like a substring in java references a shared array, at least in the openjdk version.  And if you want to ensure a new string there's a way to do that.

Comment: @Nir: I call it "status quo bias". To you the Java way of doing it seems fraught with risks and the .Net way the only sensbile choice. To Java programmers, the opposite is the case.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - you are probably right - but I can say for my defense that I've learned Java before .net and I've always found it to be fraught with risk and not sensible (but much less so than C++ that I had the "pleasure" to work with for over a decade)

Comment: I strongly prefer .NET, but this sounds like one thing Java got right. It is useful that a developer be *allowed* to have access to a truly O(1) Substring method (without rolling your own string type, which would hinder interoperability with every other library, and wouldn't be as efficient as a built-in solution). Java's solution is probably inefficient though (requiring at least two heap objects, one for the original string and another for the substring); languages that support slices effectively replace the second object with a pair of pointers on the stack.

Comment: [Since JDK 7u6 it's not true anymore](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-June/010370.html) - now Java always copies String contents for each `.substring(...)`.

Answer (score 12):

Java used to reference larger strings, but:

#### [Java changed its behavior to *copying*](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) as well, to avoid leaking memory.

I feel like it can be improved though: why not just do the copying conditionally?

If the substring is at least half the size of the parent, one can reference the parent. Otherwise one can just make a copy. This avoids leaking a lot of memory while still providing a significant benefit.

Comment: Always copying allows you to remove the internal array. Halves the number of heap allocations, saving memory in the common case of short strings. It also means you don't need to jump through an additional indirection for each character access.

Comment: I think the important thing to take from this is that Java actually changed from using the same base `char[]` (with different pointers to the start and end) to creating a new `String`. This clearly shows that the cost-benefit analysis must show a preference for the creation of a new `String`.

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers here addressed "the bracketing problem", which is to say that strings in .NET are represented as a combination of a BStr (the length stored in memory "before" the pointer) and a CStr (the string ends in a '\0').

The string "Hello there" is thus represented as

```
0B 00 00 00 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 72 00 65 00 00 00
```

(if assigned to a `char*` in a `fixed`-statement the pointer would point to the 0x48.)

This structure allows for fast lookup of the length of a string (useful in many contexts) and allows for the pointer to be passed in a P/Invoke to Win32 (or other) APIs which expect a null-terminated string.

When you do `Substring(0, 5)` the "oh, but I promised there'd be a null-character after the last character" rule says you need to make a copy.  Even if you got the substring at the end then there'd be no place to put the length without corrupting the other variables.

---

Sometimes, though, you really do want to talk about "the middle of the string", and you don't necessarily care about the P/Invoke behavior.  The recently added `ReadOnlySpan<T>` structure can be used to get a no-copy substring:

```
string s = "Hello there";
ReadOnlySpan<char> hello = s.AsSpan(0, 5);
ReadOnlySpan<char> ell = hello.Slice(1, 3);
```

The `ReadOnlySpan<char>` "substring" stores the length independently, and it does not guarantee that there's a '\0' after the end of the value.  It can be used in many ways "like a string", but it is not "a string" since it doesn't have either BStr or CStr characteristics (much less both of them).  If you never (directly) P/Invoke then there's not much of a difference (unless the API you want to call doesn't have a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` overload).

`ReadOnlySpan<char>` cannot be used as the field of a reference type, so there's also `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` (`s.AsMemory(0, 5)`), which is an indirect way of having a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, so the same differences-from-`string` exist.

Some of the answers/comments on previous answers talked about it being wasteful to have the garbage collector have to keep a million-character string around while you continue to talk about 5 characters.  That is precisely the behavior you can get with the `ReadOnlySpan<char>` approach.  If you're just doing short computations, the ReadOnlySpan approach is probably better.  If you need to persist it for a while and you're going to keep only a small percentage of the original string, doing a proper substring (to trim off the excess data) is probably better.  There's a transition point somewhere in the middle, but it depends on your specific usage.

Comment: The `48 00 65 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 72 00 65 00` part only has one `6C 00` so it's actually `"Helo there"` instead of `"Hello there"` 