# Fast substring in scala

Tags: string, scala, substring

According to [Time complexity of Java's substring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring), java's substring takes linear time.
Is there a faster way (may be in some cases)?
I may suggest iterator, but suspect that it also takes O(n).

```
val s1: String  = s.iterator.drop(5).mkString
```

But several operations on an iterator would be faster than same operations on string, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to edit very long string, consider using data structure called [Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29).

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library has [Cord](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Cord.scala) class which is implementation of modified version of Rope.

> A `Cord` is a purely functional data structure for efficiently
>   storing and manipulating `String`s that are potentially very long.
>   Very similar to `Rope[Char]`, but with better constant factors and a
>   simpler interface since it's specialized for `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

As Strings are - according to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring) - always backed by a unique character array, `substring` can't be faster than O(n). You need to copy the character data.

As for alternatives: there will at least be one operation which is O(n). In your example, that's `mkString` which collects the characters in the iterator and builds a string from them.

However, I wouldn't worry about that too much. The fact that you're using a high level language means (should mean) that developer time is more valuable than CPU time for your particular task. `substring` is also the canonical way to ... take a substring, so using it makes your program more readable.

EDIT: I also like this sentence (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750591/371191)) a lot: **O(n) is O(1) if n does not grow large.** What I take away from this is: you shouldn't write inefficient code, but asymptotical efficiency is not the same as real-world efficiency.

Comment: Totally agree, but what about large strings (like 1M or larger)?

Comment: @ChelovekChelovechnii In that case, String maybe isn't for you. I'd edit the question to clarify that you are not asking about Strings exclusively, but any data structures for large character sequences.